# Use existing DLL in iOS app through mono framework

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

For one of my current iOS project, some business logic has been provided to me through a DLL and Native C++ binding code that i have to recompile in a dynamic library (dylib)  and then  use the DLL through this dynamic library. 
Finally the DLL is used like this example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  RTEnvironnement::CreateRTEnvironnement("../dll/RT.dll");
  RT::RT_Facade *  mFacade = new RT::RT_Facade();
  RT::RT_Data_Projet *  mProjet = new RT::RT_Data_Projet();
  mProjet->Load_From_XMLFile(argv[1]);
...
```

Objects RTEnvironnement, RT_Facade, RT_Data_Projet are provided by the binding C++ dynamic lib. I cannot get the code of the base DLL and i have to use the DLL as it is on IOS.

I'm currently studying if mono touch can able my IOS app (basic iOS Objective C based on Xcode ), to launch the DLL that as been build with the standard mono framework. Before purchasing a license, I have to be sure that MonoTouch is able to do this.

Is someone do something similar ? Is there a simplest way to this ? 
If i choose to use MonoTouch, can i keep my project in Xcode and just build the dylib in MonoDevelop and then import the lib the Xcode project ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just try out the Trial of Monotouch. You are only limited to use only the iPhone-simulator - everything else is like the fully licensed version.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot use a Mono library in an Obj-C application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the DLL that as been build with the standard mono framework.

MonoTouch (like Mono for Android) provide a base class library (BCL) profile that is similar (a superset) to Silverlight. However it's a subset of the whole Mono framework.

As such it's **very** common that assemblies compiled against the full framework won't work on MonoTouch **unless** they are re-compiled (against the MonoTouch BCL).

> If i choose to use MonoTouch, can i keep my project in Xcode and just build the dylib in MonoDevelop and then import the lib the Xcode project ?

It's more complicated than that (e.g. MonoDevelop won't give you a .dylib). You *might* be able to google some instructions to do this, however be aware that this scenario is **unsupported**.

An supported alternative is to make MonoTouch drive the application, load any assemblies you need, expose those and then transfer control to your Objective-C code.